# Is it cheating to invent a language for code golf?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

With people using such cryptic languages as Jelly, where is the line? can I write my own compiler that solves the problem in a more wordy language when I type the number '0'? I can see that this is immoral and ruins the point of code golf, but how do you decide which languages are legal and which ones aren't?